# Как искать и отправлять коллекции MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord

Есть команда `/dbcheck`, к ней есть параметр **find**

find - что искать.

Мне нужно, когда человек пишет команду `/dbcheck userID: 123456789az` бот искал в коллекциях БД: "`userID: 123456789az`" и весь "блок" коллекции где нашел это отправлял человеку который вызвал команду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендую использовать `JSON.parse`:

```js
const prefix = '/';

client.on('msg', async (msg) => {
  if (msg.author.bot) return;

  let args = msg.trim().split(' ');
  let cmd = args.shift();

  if (!cmd.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  cmd = cmd.slice(prefix.length);

  if (cmd === 'dbcheck') {
    if (!args[0]) return msg.reply('Вы не указали, что искать');
    let findFilter = {};
    try {
      findFilter = JSON.parse(args.join(' '));
    } catch (err) {
      return msg.reply('Не удалось преобразовать аргумент!')
    }

    // 
    // Прошу обратить внимание, что переменную Model Вы должны заменить на свою!
    // 
    let result = await Model.find(findFilter).catch((err) => {
      return msg.reply(`Возникла ошибка: \`${err}\``);
    });

    return msg.reply(`Найденные результаты:\n\`\`\`json\n${JSON.stringify(result)}\`\`\``);
  }
})
```

Использование команды должно выглядеть так:

`/dbcheck { "userID": "1234" }`